# How I can make proxi all assets from the service http://127.0.0.1:4000 to my domain

Tags: nginx

I have the 'Angular ssr' app on the 4000 port.
And I would like to relate my website to this app via Nginx.
I wrote config

```
server {
    server_name tsame-domain.ru www.same-domain.ru;
    charset UTF-8;
    index index.html;
    disable_symlinks if_not_owner from=$root_path;
    include /etc/nginx/vhosts-includes/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/vhosts-resources/same-domain.ru/*.conf;
    access_log /var/www/httpd-logs/same-domain.ru.access.log;
    error_log /var/www/httpd-logs/same-domain.ru.error.log notice;
    ssi on;
    root $root_path;
    
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4000;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|js|css|mp3|ogg|mpe?g|avi|zip|gz|bz2?|rar|swf)$ {
            expires 5d;
        }
    }
    
    gzip on;
    gzip_comp_level 9;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript;
    set $root_path /var/www/www-root/data/www/same-domain.ru;
    listen 91.**.**.122:80 default_server;
}
```

And when I open same-domain.ru, it works but without any styles.
I explain: If I open http://91.**.**.122:4000/assets/scc/style.css - it works, but when I open same-domain.ru/assets/scc/style.css - it doesn't work.
Question: How I can make proxi all assets from http://127.0.0.1:4000 to my domain?

Comment: Be sure to use correct server IP under location block.

Comment: I check again, it is correct

Comment: Did you link the nginx to work with your created sites-enabled and sites-available? Be sure you have unlinked and deleted the default file.